# When do I carry out unit testing in the development workflow?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I teach myself to code. I've read about TDD/BDD which encourages programmers to write a failing test first, and subsequently write a code to make the test pass.

But then I encounter the continuous integrating (CI) workflow - after the codes are committed, and test passes, it will be deployed to the production immediately. How does the test in the CI workflow differs than the one developers write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But only it **shouldn't** necessarily get deployed to Production immediately after a new commit that doesn't break the CI (test pass).

The test that the developers have written is the same one that gets run in the CI, but in a different environment (to avoid the "it works on my machine" issue).